# sinon - Stubbing function that does not exist

Tags: javascript, sinon, jsdom

How is it possible that this code results in `Attempted to wrap undefined property MouseEvent as function`?

```
            window.MouseEvent = function() {};
            sinon.stub(window, 'MouseEvent', function() {
                console.log('CALLED MOUSE EVENT!');
                return {
                    _type: 'click',
                };
            });
```

I'm trying to work with an antiquated version of jsdom if someone by chance has clues of a better road to go down.

Comment: Which browser returns this exception?

Comment: old version of jsdom.